# Start interval after time delay and stop on button release / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I am trying to build a simple plus/minus-control in React. When clicked on either plus or minus (triggered by `onMouseDown`) the value should change by a defined step and when the button is held the value should in-/decrease at a specified interval after a specified delay. When the button is released (`onMouseUp`), the interval should stop.

The code below runs ok on `onMouseDown` and hold, but when I just click on the button the interval starts anyway. I see that I need to make sure that the button is still down before the interval is started, but how do I achieve that? Thank you for any insights.

```
let plusTimer = useRef(null);

const increment = () => {
  setMyValue(prev => prev + myStep);
  setTimeout(() => {
    plusTimer.current = setInterval(
      () => setMyValue(prev => prev + myStep),
      100
    );
  }, 500);
};

const intervalClear = () => {
  clearInterval(plusTimer.current);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I will let the code speak for itself:

```js
const {useCallback, useEffect, useState} = React;

const CASCADE_DELAY_MS = 1000;
const CASCADE_INTERVAL_MS = 100;

function useDelayedCascadeUpdate(intervalTime, delay, step, callback) {
  const [started, setStarted] = useState(false);
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);
  const update = useCallback(() => callback((count) => count + step), [
    callback,
    step
  ]);
  const handler = useCallback(() => {
    update();
    setStarted(true);
  }, [update, setStarted]);
  const reset = useCallback(() => {
    setStarted(false);
    setRunning(false);
  }, [setStarted, setRunning]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (started) {
      const handler = setTimeout(() => setRunning(true), delay);
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(handler);
      };
    }
  }, [started, setRunning, delay]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (running) {
      const handler = setInterval(update, intervalTime);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(handler);
      };
    }
  }, [running, update, intervalTime]);

  return [handler, reset];
}

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [incrementHandler, incrementReset] = useDelayedCascadeUpdate(
    CASCADE_INTERVAL_MS,
    CASCADE_DELAY_MS,
    1,
    setCount
  );
  const [decrementHandler, decrementReset] = useDelayedCascadeUpdate(
    CASCADE_INTERVAL_MS,
    CASCADE_DELAY_MS,
    -1,
    setCount
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <button onMouseDown={incrementHandler} onMouseUp={incrementReset}>
        +
      </button>
      <button onMouseDown={decrementHandler} onMouseUp={decrementReset}>
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. If I set DELAY_IN_MS to 100 or so, your solution will sometimes do double increments on Click and will start fast increment immediately on MouseDown and Hold. I probably didn't give enough information: I would like to have a time delay (500ms in my code) after the first increment and therafter the fast increment should start. If the user releases the button within the initial waiting period of 500ms the counter should increment by just 1.

Comment: @x-feed Please have a look into the new code above.

Comment: Excellent - that is working. Vielen Dank!